# DF.Write.mode("overwrite").save_as_table("table1) statement converts table1 definition of NOT NULL Constraint columns into NULL Constraint Columns

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have table table1 with few columns as Not NULL Constraints columns (these are primary key columns) and some are NULL constraints columns , i have Snowpark dataframe DF with columns from table1 not null and null constraint columns values , when i call this method DF.Write.mode("overwrite").save_as_table("table1) to copy the data from dataframe DF to table1 , after i see table structure, i observed that NOT NULL constraint columns are converted into NULL columns. Is there any option in this method or setting that prevents from modification of the table structure.

DF.Write.mode("overwrite").save_as_table("table1)

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually troubleshoot is to execute the code, then look at Query History to see what Snowflake is doing behind the scenes.

I tried adding a schema that specifies NOT NULL (the third parameter in StructField) to the dataframe, like this:

```
from snowflake.snowpark.types import StringType, StructType, StructField
schema_for_table = StructType([StructField("a", IntegerType(), False), StructField("b", IntegerType(), False)])
df = session.create_dataframe([[1, 2], [3, 4]], schema_for_table)
df.write.mode("overwrite").save_as_table("saved_table")
```

After I executed the code and looked at Query History I saw that the query takes the data type into consideration but not the NULL/NOT NULL parameter.